# Controlling an animation with scrolling via jQuery .animate()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

i want to control the opacity of an element on scroll. When user scrolls down page, opacity shrinks and when you scroll back up the page to top element's opacity should return to normal. Reading the jQuery Documentation i believed this would work:

```
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  console.log($(document).scrollTop());
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 250) {
    $("#sportsImages").animate(
      {
        opacity: 0.25
      },
      2000
    );
  } else {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() < 250) {
      $("#sportsImages").animate(
        {
          opacity: 1
        },
        2000
      );
    }
  }
});
```

But unfortunately this not working as expected. The opacity is remaining @ .25 even when I scroll back up the page. Any suggestions most welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I got it to work so people know :

```
let pageScrolled = false;

$(document).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 250) {
    if (pageScrolled === false) {
      pageScrolled = true;
      $("#sportsImages")
        .stop()
        .animate({ opacity: 0.25, width: "50%", margin: "0, 25%" }, 1200);
    }
  } else {
    if (pageScrolled === true) {
      pageScrolled = false;
      $("#sportsImages")
        .stop()
        .animate({ opacity: 1, width: "100%", margin: "0" }, 1200);
    }
  }
});
```